# Autolayout constraints for inscribed view

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have a view and it's subview. I want to define subview constraints to be the following:

1. Center X & Center Y of view and subview coincide (easy!),
2. Subview width & height are equal to

   ```
   min(view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height)
   ```

   How do I express this in terms of Autolayout constraints?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892559/auto-layout-y-position-as-the-max-of-two-values

Comment: Did you try setting trailing, leading, top, bottom with a low priority, and width == height with high priority?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

- Aspect Ratio of 1:1 with Priority: 1000
- CenterX & CenterY with Priority: 1000
- Top / Bottom / Leading / Trailing all set to `>= 0` with Priority: 1000
- Width = SuperviewWidth with Priority: 999
- Height = SuperviewHeight with Priority: 999

[image]